# Multipass with QEmu driver: how to access usb camera

Tags: usb, qemu, lxd, ros, multipass

on my Asus rog laptop with ubuntu 23.10 I installed the ROS (robot os) image from multipass, as explained in this official guide https://ubuntu.com//blog/ros-development-on-linux-windows-and-macos .
I need to work on Slam algorithms and need access to usb cameras, but unfortunately `lsusb` on the ros command line shows nothing.
On the host, i can see the laptop camera as usb in the output of the `lsusb` command.

```
bloom@bloom-ROG-Strix-G614JZ-G614JZ:~/sw_develop/Temp$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 322e:2122 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The local driver for multipass appears to be Qemu, as per

```
bloom@bloom-ROG-Strix-G614JZ-G614JZ:~/sw_develop/Temp$ multipass get
local.driver qemu
```

- Is it possible to configure Qemu used by multipass?
- Is it possible to configure Qemu so that the next time I start the
  noetic ROS image i will be able to use the laptop camera or any other
  usb camera?
- if not possible with Qemu, would it be possible with other drivers like lxd, etc?